# Resource 'VM_global_library.vm' not found

Tags: java, spring, maven

I download the code [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program)
and use `maven install`
and then,I got error when run on server(Tomcat)
Please help me.

```
 Velocity  [debug] org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: WebappLoader : Resource 'VM_global_library.vm' not found.
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.WebappLoader.getResourceStream(WebappLoader.java:179)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ResourceLoader.resourceExists(ResourceLoader.java:224)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getLoaderForResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:641)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getLoaderNameForResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:624)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getLoaderNameForResource(RuntimeInstance.java:1464)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.VelocimacroFactory.initVelocimacro(VelocimacroFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:261)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:107)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet.initVelocity(VelocityViewServlet.java:378)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet.init(VelocityViewServlet.java:207)
    at org.apache.struts2.sitemesh.VelocityDecoratorServlet.init(VelocityDecoratorServlet.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1900)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your velocity library or just create an empty file with that name, it should do the trick.